# Finding a constraint on one variable of a multivariable function to constrain the entire function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima, constraints

I have a function. 
Now I want to let my variables only take values between 0, and 1. 
The problem is as follows. For what values of Y, is L(x,y) < 0.
That is, without putting a further constraint on x(other than its between 0, 1), how can you bind Y, such that you bind L(x,y) below 0. 
I graphed it out, and there is visually a range of y such that this is true. 
I was unable to proceed. I thought of trying the mins and max for x, but then I noticed that really doesn't give me any useful information. I understand that the last inequality must be true for whenever L<0, including the range im looking for, but there must be some other point I am not taking into account that will give me a range independent of x.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the four optimization problems, which cover the combinations of minimizing or maximizing y, when x is fixed at 0 or 1.

a) min w.r.t. y subject to $0 \le y \le 1, L(x,y) < 0, x = 0$

b) max w.r.t. y subject to $0 \le y \le 1, L(x,y) < 0, x = 0$

c) min w.r.t. y subject to $0 \le y \le 1, L(x,y) < 0, x = 1$

d) max w.r.t. y subject to $0 \le y \le 1, L(x,y) < 0, x = 1$

Solving these as having non-strict inequality $L(x,y) \le 0$, the following solutions are obtained:

a) x = 0, y = 1/3

b) x = 0, y = 1

c) x = 1, y = 0

d) x = 1, y = 2/5.5

Given the linearity of L(x,y) for a fixed x, we can conclude that

when x = 0, then y in the interval (1/3,1] satisfies L(x,y) < 0

when x = 1, then y in the interval [0,2.5/5) satisfies L(x,y) < 0.

Due to the bilinearity of L(x,y), x = 0 and 1 are the extreme cases for x in [0,1] with regard to minimum and maximum possible values of y satisfying L(x,y) < 0.

Noting that 2.5/5 = 0.3626... we can therefore conclude that every value of y in the interval (1/3,2.5/5), and only values of y in that interval, will satisfy L(x,y) < 0 no matter which (i.e., "worst case") value of x in [0,1] is chosen.

Comment: What do you mean when you say linearity? "Given the linearity of L(x,y) for a fixed x" do you mean for a fixed x it is linear in x or y? What exactly is the reasoning behind using edges?

Comment: For a fixed x, L(x,y) is linear in y.

Comment: What do you mean by "using edges" in your comment question "What exactly is the reasoning behind using edges?"? Are you asking about my use of the term "extreme cases".?  I chose x = 0 and x = 1 as extreme cases, because no intermediate value of x could lead to more extreme bounds on possible y because L(x,y) is linear in y for a fixed x.

Comment: You have now changed the question so as to eliminate the specification of particular function L(x,y). For such a general case, no conclusions can be drawn in general. Nothing in my answer or previous comments necessarily holds for your edited question. However, if you can state that L(x,y) is bilinear, i.e., linear in y when x is fixed and linear in x when y is fixed, then the methodology I stated above still applies, even though the solution may change.